# How do I distinguish a 49.90 Hz sine wave from a 49.95 Hz one in a short audio recording?

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, noise, spectrogram, superresolution

I've read an article about "mains hum" forensics in http://hummingbirdclock.info/about and about [Electrical network frequency analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_network_frequency_analysis).
The idea is to be able to measure the small variations of the 50 Hz power line hum.

Is it said that the power line frequency is changing every second.

**Given a 96 kHz audio recording signal (with a mains hum) of a few seconds, how do I measure if the mains hum frequency is 49.90 or 49.95 Hz, or 50.04 Hz?**

To do this with a spectrogram FFT, we would need frequency bins of width 0.01 Hz, so this means we would need at least 5 million samples, nearly *1 minute* of audio recording.

Then the variation of the frequency second after second is lost... if it is averaged on a 1 minute interval.

**How to perform such a frequency measurement on a short time frame of a few seconds?**

Of course we can look at the harmonics, but I'm not sure it will be enough here.

Comment: 0.05 kHz is $\frac{1}{20} ms^{-1}$, so you will need more than 20 ms of audio.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson It is a 0.05Hz or 0.01Hz difference, and not kHz (typo).

Comment: Okay, just change milliseconds to seconds.

Comment: Can you do it by solving amplitude at nπ (when 0 it's 50Hz, otherwise != 50Hz)? Example: At 2$\pi$  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ayisizch7u .

Comment: You're looking for the frequency of sine wave that produces the highest spike when multiplied by the input signal, I think. (Ignoring phase - so using sine and cosine,, like a Fourier transform does, and taking the absolute value or squared amplitude)

Answer (score 1):

A few routes that come to mind:

1. Use phase information to refine your frequency estimates.
2. If you have good processing power, maybe a [constant Q transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-Q_transform) can help.
3. Track the hum frequency using an adaptive algorithm such as an [adaptive notch filter](https://hal-amu.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01956284/document) (the stronger the hum, the better it will perform of course, a pre-filter could help).

Comment: Do you think there is ready to use code for this in Python scipy?

Comment: yes, google is your friend ;)

Answer (score 1):

That's a difference of about 1.5cent, which a really good tuner may be able to resolve. I would try a PLL with a very low time constant (maybe 0.5s or so).

Comment: Thanks. How would you do this in Python or Matlab? If we have a 3-second signal, would you know how to deteremine the frequency?